# Confusing behavior when running script from cron

Tags: bash, cron, scrot-command

I have a simple script. Here's the code:

```bsh
#/bin/bash


saveLoc="/root/test";
dt=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S');
scrot_name_fmt="${dt}.jpeg";
streamer_name_fmt="${dt}.jpeg";


# This captures the current screen
cd `echo ${saveLoc}/1`;
/usr/bin/scrot -z -b `echo $scrot_name_fmt`;

# This captures the webcam
cd `echo ${saveLoc}/2`;
/usr/bin/streamer -f jpeg -o `echo $streamer_name_fmt`;

echo "${dt} saved";
```

This script does two things:

1. Take screenshot and save it in `/root/test/1` directory
2. Take webcam shot and save it in `/root/test/2` directory

When I run the script, it works as expected and I see two image files added to each directory. When the script is run by cron, I see the webcam shot in directory 2 but no screenshot in directory 1. Here's the cron job setup:

```bsh
* * * * * root sh /root/test/script.sh >> /root/test/logScript.log
```

Don't know what could be the problem and some help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried dividing the above into 2 scripts. I ran both script from terminal and it worked as expected. Script 1 which contained the `scrot` command is not working from cron but works when I run manually. Script 2 which contained `streamer` works both from terminal and when run by cron.

**EDIT 2**

After few hours of painstaking searches, I found out the error. gnome-screenshot cannot connect to X11 server. This is the error I got when trying to take the screenshot:

```bsh
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-screenshot:13349): Gtk-WARNING **: 06:48:01.878: cannot open display:
```

**EDIT 3**

Following suggestions from @raj, I exported `XAUTHORITY`. It didn't work. Here's the script after all changes:

```bsh
#/bin/bash

export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority;
save_loc="/root/test";
dt=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S');
scrot_name_fmt="${dt}.jpeg";
streamer_name_fmt="${dt}.jpeg";


# This captures the current screen
cd `echo $save_loc/1`;
echo `pwd`;
DISPLAY=:0
/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot -b -f `echo $scrot_name_fmt`;

# This captures the webcam
cd `echo $save_loc/2`;
echo `pwd`;
/usr/bin/streamer -f jpeg -o `echo $streamer_name_fmt`;

echo "screenshot ${dt} saved";
echo "cam-shot ${dt} saved";
```

**Final Edit**

I am adding this for @bac0n. This is similar in principle to what he suggested in his answer. This was tested in Ubuntu 20.04

```bsh
# Locate Xauthority
for I in /run/user/*; do
    # get the number of directory 
    d="`echo $I | awk -F '/' '{ print $4 }'`";
    if [ $d -eq "121" ]; then
        # Root user; continue
        continue;
    else
        # now locate the Xauthority in gdm
        # loads Xauthority for current user only
        for J in /run/user/$d/gdm/*; do
            AUTHUSER="`echo $J | awk -F '-' '{ print $3 }'`";
            for K in $USER; do
                [ "${AUTHUSER}" = "${K}" ] || continue;
                USER="${K}";
                export XAUTHORITY="/run/user/${d}/gdm/Xauthority";
                break;
            done;
        done;
    fi;
done;
```

This works but looks ugly.

Comment: try adding display to scrot `scrot -D :0.0` ...

Comment: No need to use `command ´echo ${string}´`. just use plain string as you do on the variables.

Comment: @bac0n I changed the `echo ${string}` as you said. Also tried adding `-D` flag but, `scrot` did not recognize that. I used `-d` instead (which is delay). Still same result. Only webcam shot was saved; nothing on screenshot

Comment: easiest would probably be to run scrot with the same user you intend to screenshot... keep `-D ":0.0"`

Comment: Well... where exactly is the "screen" the cron script is supposed to take screenshot from?
Cron script runs in a completely independent environment from your desktop session, it doesn't know anything about your screen.

Comment: @raj What if I add `DISPLAY=:0` before the cron task in the crontab file? Will that work?

Comment: It may work, try it. It is also possible that you will need to provide the XAUTHORITY variable to your script as well, to give it authorization to connect to display.

Comment: @raj Adding `DISPALY=:0` did not work; now it says can't open DISPLAY=:0

Comment: @raj how can I add xAUTHORITY for my script? I added the following: `if [ "$XAUTHORITY" ]; then
    cp -f "$XAUTHORITY" ~/.Xauthority
fi` in the user's `$HOME/.xprofile` but it did not work. Gives the same error as in EDIT 2 in the post

Comment: I don't think you need to copy the actual Xauthority file, but you need to define the value of XAUTHORITY variable in your script, because it's not defined by default.

Comment: @raj Can you show me to add this? I am not too good at BASH so it's a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Try adding a command like ```export XAUTHORITY=<insert actual value here>``` at the beginning of your script. The actual value for the variable you must obtain from your desktop session, type ```env|grep XAUTHORITY``` in the terminal.

Comment: @raj It didn't work. I updated the question with the code. Please check

Comment: Try using ```export``` before ```DISPLAY=:0``` as well. If this still doesn't work, you need to use something like ```env >/tmp/env.out``` in your script and by analyzing the ```/tmp/env.out``` file compare environment variables defined in your cron script and in your desktop session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maim screenshot tool aims to be a better choice than scrot. Systemd.timer works as a time-based activation. By default, your timer activates a service with the same name. Scheduling your task, you can either use a real-time timer defined by calendar expressions or monotonic timers that start the moment the timer itself activates (or you can combine them both).

*/etc/systemd/system/maim-screenshot.timer:*

```
[Unit]
Description=Take a screenshot every 15 minutes.

[Timer]
OnBootSec=5m
OnUnitActiveSec=15m

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

*/etc/systemd/system/maim-screenshot.service:*

```
[Unit]
Description=Maim Screenshot service.

[Service]
UMask=0077
ExecStart=/opt/bin/maim_screenshot.sh
```

The script iterates all logged-in sessions, looking for x11 sessions. The script then tries to use the user's Xauthority file located in the user's home directory. The Xauthority file will allow maim to run as root.

*/opt/bin/maim_screenshot.sh*

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Based on maim (make image) utility.

# Screenshot folder.
mkdir -m 750 -p /opt/images; images=$_

b=($(loginctl show-seat seat0 \
    -p Sessions --value --no-legend))

mapfile -t < <(loginctl show-session ${b[@]} \
    -p User -p Display -p Type --all | tr -s \\n)

declare -A A
((c=${#MAPFILE[@]} / ${#b[@]}))
for ((d=0, e=0; $d < ${#b[@]}; d++, e+=$c)); do
    A=()
    for f in "${MAPFILE[@]:$e:$c}"; do
        [[ $f =~ ^([^=]*)=(.*)$ ]] && \
        A[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    done
    if [[ ${A[Type]} = x11 ]] \
        && [[ $(getent passwd ${A[User]}) \
        =~ ([^:]*:){5}([^:]+) ]] \
        && [[ -r ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/.Xauthority ]]
    then
        XAUTHORITY=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/.Xauthority \
        maim -x "${A[Display]}" -i root "/$images/screenshot_$EPOCHSECONDS.jpg"
    fi
done
exit 0
```

Last we need to make the script executable and start the timer.

```
$ chmod +x /opt/bin/maim_screenshot.sh
$ systemctl enable --now maim-screenshot.timer
```

Comment: Running it as a system timer/service adds a lot of complexity. The only reason as I can see it is if you want to protect the screenshot from user tampering.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I actually found something similar for loading the proper `Xauthority` file for the logged in user and was able to make `scrot` work as expected using `/etc/crontab`. Your solution also works (and is a lot neater). Thanks so much for taking the time to help.

Comment: I could get scrot to work, when I switched to  'console' (vt2), I only got black screenshots.

Comment: If you create timer/service as a systemctl `--user` ... timer/service you could probably skip the script altogether and run maim directly in the service file `ExecStart=maim ...`

Comment: I added the snippet I used for your reference.