# notify-send doesn't work in systemd service

Tags: bash, xubuntu, systemd, notify-send

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/notify-send 'lol'
#function check_state () {
    #toggle_toggle=$(/usr/bin/amixer get Capture | grep -c "\[off\]")
    #echo toggle+percent
    #toggle_percent=$(/usr/bin/amixer get Capture | grep -c "\[0%\]")
    #echo toggle_percent
    #let toggle_result=$((toggle_toggle+toggle_percent))
    #echo $((toggle_result))
#}
#check_state 
#echo $toggle_result # IF 4  = TURNED OFF, IF !=4 TURNED ON

#if [ $((toggle_result)) != 4 ] ; then
        # toggle off
#        /usr/bin/killall -9 xfce4-notifyd
#        /usr/bin/notify-send 'Microphone was left turned on' 'It was automatically disabled.'
#   /usr/bin/amixer set Capture toggle
#        /usr/bin/amixer set Capture 0
#        /usr/bin/amixer set Capture 0%
#fi

exit 0
```

Service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Warns if microphone is turned on at startup
After=sound.target
After=display-manager.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/bin/microphone-status
RemainAfterExit=yes
Environment="DISPLAY=:0.0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/tom/.Xauthority"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that when i run systemctl start microphone-status.service, it works. On boot up, doesn't. I dont understand the reason

It succeded:

```
sudo systemctl status microphone-status.service 
[sudo] password for tom: 
● microphone-status.service - Warns if microphone is turned on at startup
     Loaded: loaded (/opt/bin/microphone-status.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2020-12-22 20:53:08 CET; 9min ago
    Process: 759 ExecStart=/opt/bin/microphone-status (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 759 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 22 20:53:08 UNKNOWN-PC systemd[1]: Started Warns if microphone is turned on at startup.
```

EDIT1:

```
[Unit]
Description=Turns off microphone at startup
#After=multi-user.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/bin/microphone-status
User=tom
RemainAfterExit=yes
Environment="DISPLAY=:0.0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/tom/.Xauthority"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: does `microphone-status` need to be run as root?

Comment: at boot it may run it before desktop is active or before `notify` is active - so it can't display it. Did you try to save text in file (log) to check if it really was executed? Maybe you should run it in `.bashrc` which is executed when you login and when your desktop is already running.

Comment: @bac0n yes it needs to be run as root since it contains /usr/bin/killall -9 xfce4-notifyd

Comment: @furas thats what i was thinking let me try but i would rather assign it to an existing service for consistency.

Comment: @furas how do i put it in bashrc? Just the script?

Comment: `.bashrc` (with dot at the beginning) is normal bash script which can run other script at start - so you can put line `/opt/bin/microphone-status` directly in `.bashrc`. You should already have  in in your home folder `~/.bashrc`. It may have disadvantage - `.bashrc` can be automatically executed every time when you run console/terminal - but it can  advantage - it will check microphone periodically.

Comment: @furas is it safe to put things like that in there? i only want my script to be executed once on startup.

Comment: @bac0n do you have any other suggestions besides .bashrc? I dont feel like that's a good place to put my scripts. And Why don't my service work in the first place?

Comment: did something [similar](https://askubuntu.com/a/1275752/986805) couple of month ago not sure if you can reuse some of it, obviously, you don't need the timer and probably need to add something like *After=graphical.target*

Comment: you could use a service and make another as a autostart .desktop just for checking the status or use sudo

Comment: This looks like a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. Why do you have to do it at all?

Comment: What about a user service ?

Comment: @Marco see my edit, i added user, it still doesnt work properly

Comment: @Marco Now i put my service to /etc/user/system and used systemctl daemon-reload and it does't even detect it with systemctl status...

Comment: User services are in the users home directory and started on with `systemctl --user start test.service`. see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd/User

Comment: @Marco yes and it says "Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory"

Comment: you need dbus as communication component.